# Find the Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

How would one write

$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-wz}$ as a power series? ( Where $z,w$ are in $C$.)

Would it just be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (zw)^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming $|zw|<1$.  $\mbox{        }$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for $|zw|<1$, if we are intersted not only in the formal series.